# Approximating Gallons of Gas Needed for Trip (read: physics grad. with too much free time)

Tags: soft-question, everyday-life, home-experiment, approximations

> My departure from college has left me with an itch for physics-y problems to solve, and my boredom and free time gave way to this approximation of the gallons of gas I use for the trip to my girlfriends house.

1. **First approximated miles per gallon (mpg) as a function of velocity [mph]**

$\boxed{mpg(v)}$:

[image: MPG(v)]

(Function approximated from this image from the [Wikipedia page on Fuel Economy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fuel_economy_in_automobiles#/media/File:Fuel_economy_vs_speed_1997.png))

[image: MPG2(v)]

2. **Then approximated the speed (mph) as a function of time (hrs) for the trip. (n.b. this graph assumed no traffic, and is therefor horribly inaccurate as I live in LA, and there's literally always traffic in LA)**

**$\boxed{v(t)}$:**

[image: v(t)]

3. **Checked the approximation by integrating $v(t) \ dt$ over the trip and checking that the total distance travelled was right (it was :D)**

$\boxed{x(t)}$:

[image: x(t)]

4. **Then used $mpg(v)$ and $v(t)$ to get $mpg(v(t))=mpg(t)$.**

$\boxed{mpg(t)}$:

[image: mpg(t)]

5. **The reciprocal of miles per gallon is gallons per mile, i.e. $\dfrac{1}{mpg(t)}=gpm(t)$, so I assumed that gallons per mile times miles per hour would give gallons per hour as a function of time $\dfrac{v(t)}{mpg(t)}=gph(t)$**

$\boxed{gph(t)}$:

[image: gph(t)]

6. **Then integrated $gph(t) \ dt$ over the whole trip to get gallons used**:

[image: gallons]

> **However, this seems quite low**. From personal experience, I'd say I use closer to 2 gallons for this trip. I'd say my assumption of no traffic probably had *some* effect, but even with that correction, it's still only around 1.5.
>
> **Did I make any glaringly false assumptions?**
> **Any way I could make this approx. more accurate?**
>
> Also, for anyone who knows cars, why does it seem like I use gas more quickly when my gas tank is less full than when its more full? One would think that less gas=less weight=better fuel economy... Something to do with the shape of the tank?

Comment: Mpg(v) is steady state? What about the cost of acceleration?

Comment: "why does it seem like I use gas more quickly when my gas tank is less full than when its more full? One would think that less gas=less weight=better fuel economy... Something to do with the shape of the tank?" Probably because the gauge is not a linear function of the volume of remaining fuel.